# How to resolve this error while making bar graph?

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plotdata = pd.DataFrame({
    "Attack 0":[57,67,77,83],    
    "Attack 1":[68,73,80,79],    
    "Attack 2":[73,78,80,85],
    "Attack 3":[73,78,80,85],    
    "Attack 4":[73,78,80,85]},    
    index=["Attack 0", "Attack 1", "Attack 2", "Attack 3", "Attack 4"])

plotdata.plot(kind="bar",figsize=(15, 8))
plt.xlabel("Different Malware Assaults")    
plt.ylabel("Accuracy")
```

The error that I'm getting is `ValueError: Shape of passed values is (4, 4), indices imply (5, 4)`.

Comment: If you want **index** as written in your example than input data has to be changed from dictionary to a list like `[[57,67,77,83], ... [73,78,80,85]]`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess `"Attack 0", "Attack 1", ...` are the labels of the columns, not the rows.

So you have to use the keyword `columns=["Attack 0", "Attack 1, ..."` instead of `index=["Attack 0", "Attack 1, ..."` when you construct your DataFrame.